# set emissiveIntensity in a-image (or on any material)

Tags: aframe

Using aframe, I would like to display a flat image with transparency (e.g. as png) which is dark when no light points at it. The parameter I figured out is emissiveIntensity, which is not recognized when using a-image (according to the console of my Chrome Browser):

```
<a-image src="#img-colorwheel" 
         position="8 3 -10"
         rotation="0 0 0"
         height="5" 
         width="5"
         material="emissiveIntensity:0;">
</a-image>
```

When using a regular a-entity, it works:

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive: plane; height:5; width:5;" 
          material="src:#img-colorwheel; emissiveIntensity:0;"
          position="0 2 -19.9"
          rotation="0 0 0">
</a-entity>
```

My problem is, that in this case the transparent part of the png is displayed in white color.
Any hints - or workarounds?

Working with a-frame 0.7.0; same issue with 0.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<a-image>` does  not have the emissive [mappings](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/primitives/a-image.html). You can also check it out, by searching for `a-image` in the [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-v0.7.1.js), where You can see the mappings.

I would use the entity, since the `a-image` is clearly an abridged version of `a-entity` with the `plane` geometry.

---

If You really need the `<a-image>` with emissive, You need to change the shader, since `<a-image>` uses the [meshBasicMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshBasicMaterial). Check out it's properties. No emissive. What needs to be done is:

```
<a-image src="https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpg" 
     position="0 2 -3"
     rotation="0 0 0"
     height="5" 
     width="5"
     material = "shader:standard;color:blue;
     emissive:red;emissiveIntensity:2">
</a-image>
```

like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qL3685ez/).

Ofc You could make a component, which changes the material to any other, but the `meshStandardMaterial` should be sufficient.